# QPushButton Geometry

Tags: qt, qwidget

Inside a `QWidget` I put a `QHBoxLayoutwith,` two `QPushButton`s and a `QLabel`. I can change the geometry of the `QWidget` that works as container for the layout but can not change the size of the `QPushButton`: here my code

```
void
QTitleBar::resizeEvent( QResizeEvent * event)
{
 QSize size = event->size();
 int widgetHeight = size.rheight();
 int widgetWidth = size.rwidth();

 std::cout << "resizeEvent h:" <<
  widgetHeight  
  << " w: " << widgetWidth << std::endl;

 int layoutH = (int)((float)widgetHeight*(float)0.20);


 std::cout << "resizeEvent h:" <<
  layoutH  
  << " w: " << widgetWidth << std::endl;

 mapButton->setGeometry(0, 0, 120, layoutH);
 titleWidget->setGeometry(0, 0,  widgetWidth, layoutH);

// title->setGeometry(130, 0, widgetWidth - (2*130), layoutH);
// closeButton->setGeometry(widgetWidth - (2*130), 0,  130, layoutH);

 //closeButton->setGeometry(0, 0,  widgetWidth, layoutH);

}
```

is there something wrong?

Comment: Does the position of button gets changed upon resizeevent? Only size remains unchanged? And what about titlewidget?? is it getting resized and relocated as in the above piece of code?

Comment: no, all is unchanged. The only thing that changes is the titleWidget geometry. Maybe is QHBoxLayoutwith fault?

Comment: check the sizehint for your mapbutton, whether it is restrained by it

Comment: for the mapButtom the sizeHint is h: 23 w:89. Should I subclass QPushButton in order to change it?

Comment: mapButton->setMinimumSize(QSize(160, layoutH)); does the trick. Is correct in your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   mapButton->setMinimumSize(QSize(0,0));
   mapButton->setMaximumSize(QSize(10000,10000));
```

Now you can set your `QPushButton` to any size (practically). I hope this would solve the problem, as titlewidget is getting resized and relocated as in code.

Comment: It seems to work. The size changes but the QWidget::size() return always the QWidget::sizeHint() value. Why is this?

Comment: @Blackbelt If *mimimumSize* and *maximumSize* contain *sizeHint*, then *size*, according to *sizePolicy*, should be initially *sizeHint*. This is the size the *QWidget* preferes. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38118293/6385043 for some references.

Answer (score 1):

[Some advice for further readers...]

As you noticed using the button's *geometry* property is not the right way, because it is controlled by the containing *QLayout*. See [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/layout.html#manual-layout) for Qt layout handling or writing an own implementation of `QLayout`.

Also note that setting the *geometry* of a `QWidget` may result in an [**infinite loop**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#geometry-prop)!

Setting the properties *height* and *width* of a `QWidget` directly works if and only if the `QWidget` is not contained in any `QLayout`. Otherwise it will be resized inside the dimension of *mimimumHeight* and *maximumHeight* which applies to *width* as pointed out. (Note that the *size* property only bundles these two.) You may influence this behaviour by modifying the `QWidget`s [*sizePolicy*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop) property.

So stick to [*ScarCode's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11686331/6385043) using

```
QWidget.setMinimumSize(QSize)
QWidget.setMaximumSize(QSize)
```

As for completness I like to point out that the size of `QPushButton` may also be changed using [Qt style sheets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qpushbutton):

```
QPushButton {
    min-width: 0px;
    max-width: 10000px;
}
```